# In Java, how can I sort objects that do not implement Comparable with my own compare criteria?

Tags: java, sorting, object, collections, comparable

Say an object has an int ID number field but does not implement Comparable. I would like to use Collections.sort() on these objects with my own sort criteria. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: How would you like them sorted specifically?

Answer (score 5):

You can provide a Comparator e.g.

```
List<MyType> list = ...
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<MyType>() {
     public int compare(MyType a, MyType b) {
         return Integer.compare(a.getX(), b.getX());
     }
});
```

In Java 8 you can do

```
list = list.stream()
           .sort(Comparator.comparingInt(MyType::getX))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or

```
Collections.sort(list, comparingInt(MyType::getX));
```

Comment: Thanks. Can someone change the C++ namespace syntax to reflect Java syntax?

Comment: :: is not only C++ namespace syntax, but also Java 8 method reference syntax

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can provide a compratator [for the sort method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-).